# Where do I find the endpoint and key for an cognitive services index

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, large-language-model, azure-openai

I am currently trying to connect a AzureOpenAI model to an index within cognitive search.

```
"dataSources": [
             {
                 "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
                 "parameters": {
                     "endpoint": "ENDPOINT",
                     "key": "KEY",
                     "indexName": "test-index" }              
             }
```

Where in Azure do I find the endpoint and key so that I can connect this index to my model?

I have tried utilising the connection string as the data source and the index primary admin key

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Those parameters are coming from your Azure Cognitive Search.

For example in the Azure Portal, with one of my resources:

- endpoint = should be `https://{NAME OF YOUR SEARCH RESOURCE}.search.windows.net`

See "URL" here:
[image: overview]

- key = use your primary or secondary search key. Not sure if you can use a
  "query key", it might be a best practice in term of security
  [image: key]
- indexName = name of your index.

Example in the "indexes" tab:
[image: indexes]

```
"dataSources": [
    {
        "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
        "parameters": {
            "endpoint": "https://{NAME OF YOUR SEARCH RESOURCE}.search.windows.net",
            "key": "YOUR SEARCH KEY",
            "indexName": "test-index"
        }
    }
```